# How to overlap divs in html

Tags: html, css

hi i am trying to make simple website( i am Learning this).
i created simple web site(Static ones). i wanted to try little up with dynamic with CSS. so tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kdGCu/).
I wanted them to over lap so that i can create nice file like looking like this

```
    _ ______  _ _______
   |N|De|N|De|N|Details|.....Etc
   |A|  |A|  |A|       |     
   |M|  |M|  |M|       |     
   |E|  |E|  |E|       |     
   |_|__|_|__|_|_______|
```

but it is looking like this

```
  _ _______  _ _______
   |N|Details||N|Details|.....Etc
   |A|       ||A|       |
   |M|       ||M|       |
   |E|       ||E|       |
   |_|_______||_|_______|
```

how to DO this
 the js fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/kdGCu/

Comment: Have you tried make `width: 5em;` instead of `width: 20em;` , I mean maybe issue in your width for `.Profile` class, Edit: or maybe I understand your issue wrongly, well, I'll see how could be.

Comment: In the markup it's `class="Child"`, but the css has `.child`. CSS ist case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well things are pretty messy in your CSS so lets do it the right way, I;ve made an example from scratch

Use a `position: relative;` container and wrap all the 3 divs and assign `position: absolute;`.

Now use `top` and `left` properties here to stack them...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LjW4D/) (Stack Up Demo)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LjW4D/1/) (Modified as per your needs)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LjW4D/2/) (Playing With `z-index` to reveal content on hover)

In CSS am using `nth-of-type` which means it will select nth type of an element, which in this case it's a `div` here

CSS

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

.wrap {
    position: relative;
}

.wrap div {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
}

.wrap div:nth-of-type(1) {
    background: #f00;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.wrap div:nth-of-type(2) {
    background: #00f;
    top: 0;
    left: 40px;
}

.wrap div:nth-of-type(3) {
    background: #0f0;
    top: 0;
    left: 80px;
}
```

Comment: how to apply to all children. like not giving the `nth-of-type()`

Comment: @manuvishwanath Simply use classes if you don't want to use `nth-of-type()` and I've edited my answer, check this out http://jsfiddle.net/LjW4D/1/

Comment: How could this answer get -1?

Comment: @micadelli That's what am asking, that -1 for what? I explained him to stack the elements in a correct way

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yeah, I'm just amazed as well... best answer to the question. Weird. Reveal yourself, downvoter!

Comment: thank you Alien. you helped a lot. this answered a lot of my future questions

Comment: @manuvishwanath You welcome :) and yes, learn CSS positioning, it will help you a lot

Comment: i Have one doubt though. you have given position for all the child's individually. can it happen for all the divs i add further on. like not specifying left and top position individually.

Comment: @manuvishwanath No, you need to give them top, left as the divs are absolute, they are out of document flow, if they were relative, then you don't have to, thy will just render one after another, like a normal document flow

Comment: @manuvishwanath In this case, yes, that's why I use `nth-of-type` so I don't have to call the classes on each and every child div, else I had to give class1, class2, class3 which will be a mess :), you should try somethings yourself, it will clear your doubts.

Comment: ok thanks. this is my first website with CSS and scripts. so learning on the go :)

Comment: @manuvishwanath Ya, build up things and you'll learn it as and when you encounter issues

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think I understand issue now, and I think I found solution, you almost done but something missing, simply I added `width` for `div.mainContainer>div` and fixes your `.Child` class, you can find solution in update on your code : http://jsfiddle.net/kdGCu/2/

```
div.mainContainer>div {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
    width: 5em;
}

.Child {
    z-index:5;
}
```

I wish I helped you.

Comment: thanks. but that child class is all having scrolls. i want them to over lap. so that i can extend it with mouse over or click.

Comment: so maybe you can make `overflow:auto;` to `overflow:hidden` and expand it with jQuery animate or what you wan to actual size?

Comment: @manuvishwanath , may you check this : http://jsfiddle.net/kdGCu/6/ its just fast demo, need fixes, I made it just as PoC .

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use negative margin.

```
.Profiles {
    width:20em;
    height:300px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius:10px;
    left:1em;
    z-index:0;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:-20px;
}
```

See this jsfiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/harendra/kdGCu/3/